# Check ALL of the following Cartesian products to find where element belongs

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

Q:
A =  {3,5,7}
B = {4,5}
Check ALL of the following Cartesian products to which the following element belong:
(5,5)

ANS:

I got
{3,4}
{5,4}
{7,4}
{3,5}
{5,5}
{7,5}

But like what element does {5,5} belong to? The options are

BxB
BxA
AxA
AxB

I was thinking either AxA or BxB or ??

Answer (score 2):

They both have a $5$ so $(5,5)$ is an element of every one of those Cartesian products.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what the cartesian product is?

The cartesian product, AxB is the set of all possible ordered pairs (a,b).

What pairs do you get by creating the cartesian product of your options?

Hint: it's in all of them. Do you see why?